# What is the reason for this falsely redirect to www.www2.example.de

Tags: web-server, .htaccess, wordpress, 301-redirect

I set up a testserver for our main website `www.example.com`.
I set the apache-sites-config to `www2.example.com`.
I deleted the `.htaccess` / adjusted it to hold the basic wordpress-entries.
I disabled the autocompletion of the browser.

When I enter `www2.example.com` I get redirected with moved permanently to `www.www2.example.com`.

When I enter `192.168.0.1` I get redirected to `www.www2.example.com`.

Could somebody tell where the error might be?

`.htaccess`:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
# END WordPress
```

`sites-config for the first vHost`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     Protocols h2 http/1.1
     ServerAdmin info@example.de
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
     ServerName www2.example.de
     ServerAlias www2.example.de

     <Directory /var/www/html>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin info@example.de
        Protocols h2 h2c http/1.1
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/
        ServerName www2.example.de
        ServerAlias www2.example.de

        # added 01.04.2019 BEGINN
        <Directory /var/www/html>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>
        # added 01.04.2019 END
        <Directory /var/www/html/>
          Options -Indexes +FollowSymlinks
          AllowOverride All
          Require all granted
         allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
        SSLEngine off
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

`sites-config for second vHost`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     Protocols h2 http/1.1
     ServerAdmin info@example.de
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html1/example2/
     ServerName www2.example2.eu
     ServerAlias www2.example2.eu

     <Directory /var/www/html1/example2>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
     </Directory>

     ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
     CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`The request- and response-header for www2.example.de`

```
Connection:     Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 236
Content-Type:   text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Date:           Wed, 26 May 2021 10:41:46 GMT
Expires:        Wed, 26 May 2021 10:42:46 GMT
Keep-Alive:     timeout=5, max=100
Location:       https://www.www2.example.de/
Server:         Apache


Accept:         text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Cache-Control:  no-cache
Connection:     keep-alive
DNT:            1
Host:           www2.example.de
Pragma:         no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:  1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0
```

Comment: There's nothing in what you've posted that would trigger such  a redirect (there are no redirects in the code you posted). If you enter `192.168.0.1` (the IP address) then the vHost you've posted wouldn't necessarily be called, unless this is the first vHost defined? _Aside:_ You have duplicated some directives and mixing old Apache 2.2 and 2.4 authorisation directives.

Comment: So what else could cause such a redirect?

Comment: its one of two vHosts and it resides in the main location for websites

Comment: Which vHost is defined first? Add the other to your question. The other vHost might be triggered when typing the IP address.

Comment: Does `www.www2.example.com` resolve? You are referring to `www2.example.com` in the question text, but your vHost definitions do not use this ServerName - please clarify. Check the HTTP response headers of the redirect - make sure it's not a cached redirect and check if there is a clue as to what is triggering the redirect... is it WordPress? (WP adds a header if it is.)

Comment: www.www2.example.de does not resolve and it should not, it is not correct. Wordpress does not add any header to the page. It is not cached and I find no clue why it is redirecting ... I am switching to cleanly disable all sites, remove the content and freshly install wordpress

Comment: How are you testing this? Please use a command line tool such as curl or wget, because a browser might have cached this on your previous attempts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SNI was sending the requests to the Live-Server instead of the test-server. And the Live-Server has rewrite-rules.

Comment: SNI? Don't you mean DNS (or perhaps HOSTS file)? Although this wouldn't explain why the local IP address was also being redirected?

Comment: No I mean SNI. Unfortunately I have no access to the SNI so I cannot tell which setting was wrong.

Comment: But the [SNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) (part of the security cert) can't "send the request" anywhere?! _Something else_ must be doing that. (?)

Answer (score 0):

You should check WordPress Site URL setting. WordPress sends back a 301 redirect to the site URL if the site URL does not match current virtual host hostname.